# Attach DirectShow video window to WPF Control

Tags: c#, wpf, video, directshow, directshow.net

I'm using DirectShow.NET to create a web camera control for WPF. I've successfully created a graph and can get video from a camera to display on my screen. However, the video output is completely independent of the WPF control it's being created in.

I am setting the owner of the video window by calling `videoWindow.put_owner(hWnd)`, where `hWnd` is the window handle to the current WPF window. I get that window handle using the `WindowInteropHelper`.

Here is the main routine:

```
public void CaptureVideo()
        {
            int hr = 0;
            IBaseFilter sourceFilter = null;

            try
            {
                hr = this.captureGraphBuilder.SetFiltergraph(this.graphBuilder);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                sourceFilter = FindCaptureDevice();

                hr = this.graphBuilder.AddFilter(sourceFilter, "Video Capture");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                hr = this.captureGraphBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, sourceFilter, null, null);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceFilter);

                SetupVideoWindow();

                hr = this.mediaControl.Run();
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An unrecoverable DirectShow error has occurred.");
            }
        }
```

And the code for SetupVideoWindow():

```
public void SetupVideoWindow()
        {
            int hr = 0;

            Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
            IntPtr hWnd = wih.Handle;

            hr = this.videoWindow.put_Owner(hWnd);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = this.videoWindow.put_WindowStyle(DirectShowLib.WindowStyle.Child | DirectShowLib.WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            this.videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height);

            hr = this.videoWindow.put_Visible(OABool.True);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
```

Here is an image of what is happening:
[image: DirectShow.NET Video Window and WPF MainWindow Control]

Comment: Last `RenderStream` call argument does not make sense. Also, it might so happen that your `hWnd` is zero/null which would explain the behavior.

Comment: @RomanR. Ah yes, I was just trying some things out and it seems like I copied the wrong code in. I edited it to reflect the actual code I'm using to produce the above results. Is it possible that hWnd is zero/null because I'm using WPF? That's the only other answer I seem to be finding around online.

Comment: So, can you debug and make sure that `hWnd` is non-zero? For zero the behavior is quite expected (nevertheless not the one you want). Perhaps you're setting it up too early before the handle even exists (allocated).

Comment: @RomanR. You were absolutely right. The handle didn't exist yet - I was making the calls in the constructor of the window. Moving the logic to after the window is loaded makes it work perfectly. Thanks! If you want to create an answer with that information, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video renderers operating in windowed mode specifically (same applies to windowless) require that you provide a valid `HWND` window handle so that video could be accurately integrated with standard UI. Your `SetupVideoWindow` code snippet is doing exactly initialization of video "as a child control".

WPF is a sort of new UI concept which does not need to create a window handle for every UI control, and there is no clear and direct property to request handle in order to pass to VMR initialization. Hence, [`WindowInteropHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper) which you use correctly except that valid handle is available as soon as it is actually allocated, which is not the form constructor.

Using a zero handle instructs video renderer to send video to desktop window and behavior you are seeing is expected and understandable.

You need to check handle value with debugger, and if it's zero then move configuration code to some later stage of form construction. Non-zero valid window handle at setup time should put video in place.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the DirectShow uses direct video memory access to present a content on a screen for the best performance, so most likely the `this.videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height);` needs to be in screen coordinates.

I.e. you need to get position of the hosting WPF window on the screen and it's size (using WinApi), and pass to the `SetWindowPosition` method. And do that every single time when your window moves/resizes.

Sorry for incomplete answer (no exact code is provided to solve the problem), because I've done that many years ago in C++ with WinApi.